# Write a shellscript from the shell, or from a shellscript?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

```
[root@centos ~]# printf "#!/bin/sh\nsomething"
-bash: !/bin/sh\nsomething": event not found
```

It fails to execute the command as a command, because it does not get saved into the command history.

Must I obfuscate the hashbang slightly in order for it to let me get past?

I tried this:

```
[root@centos ~]# printf "%s!/bin/sh\nsomething" #
-bash: !/bin/sh\nsomething": event not found
```

(Also tried `echo` to the same effect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In interactive shells, `!` is used for history substitution. You can escape it with `\` or by putting the string in single quotes:

```
printf '#!/bin/sh\nsomething'
```

See the documentation of bash [History Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction).

This won't be a problem if your actual application will be in a script, since history is not enabled by default in scripts.

If you don't ever use history expansion, you can disable the history characters with:

```
export histchars=
```

Comment: oh crap. Is it really the history substitution causing the issue? Well, the newlines do seem to take with single quotes, so that looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Well. This is a workaround that I did find:

```
[root@centos ~]# printf "#%s/bin/sh\nsomething" !
#!/bin/sh
something
```

Yep, has to be history expansion that is messing with it (the error mentioning an `event` is a big clue)

Note: I opted to use a heredoc in my script-making script. Escaping strings is hellish.